# 'INSERT' stored procedure with validation

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure where I'm inserting a new office into the `OFFICE` table I have in my database.

I want to first check whether the office I'm trying to create already exists or not.

Here is some code from where I've gotten so far, but I'm not able to quite get it right. I would greatly appreciate some input.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE stored_proc_new_office
AS 
BEGIN    
    DECLARE @office_id int
    SELECT @office_id = (SELECT office_id FROM inserted)

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM OFFICE WHERE office_id = @office_id)
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        PRINT 'Office already exists.'
    END
END
```

Comment: Stored Procedure? Or Trigger? `inserted` is only available in a trigger.

Comment: And one assumes that `id` will always be unique regardless, since it *should* be system generated. We need to know your *actual* criteria for detecting duplicate records e.g. `OfficeName` or similar. And if you are hoping to create a new record in this SP, you need to pass the information required to create a new office record in using parameters.

Comment: I guess both potentially, however, what I found here: [link](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/insert-stored-procedure-in-sql-server/), they're using insert.  Do you mean for the validation I'd need the trigger?  and yes, you're correct, it should be the office name instead of id.

Comment: No, you can create an SP with validation... just not the way you are doing it. You need to look at the example called "Insert Statements With Parameter" and then pass the details about your new office in, and then check whether it already exists before inserting it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bare bones example of how you can use a stored procedure to insert a new record with a check to ensure it doesn't already exist.

```sql
create procedure dbo.AddNewOffice
(
    @Name nvarchar(128)
    -- ... add parameters for other office details
    , @NewId int out
)
as 
begin
    set nocount on;

    insert into dbo.Office([Name]) -- ... add additional columns
    select @Name -- ... add additional parameters to match the columns above
    where not exists (select 1 from dbo.Office where [Name] = @Name); -- ... add any additional conditions for testing for uniqueness

    -- If nothing inserted return an error code for the calling app to use to display something meaningful to the user
    if @@rowcount = 0 return 99;

    -- return the new id to the calling app.
    set @NewId = scope_identity();

    return 0;
end
```